# NullReferenceException al utilizar el plugin WooCommerce.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, woocommerce

Estoy utilizando el plugin "WooCommerce.NET", para hacer la conexión entre WooCommerce (versión 2.6.*) y mi aplicación en asp.net con C# en Visual Studio 2013.

Al tratar de utilizar el método de "GetProducts()" me arroja la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya estuve "debuggeando" las clases y la excepción es producida cuando se trata de ejecutar la siguiente línea:

```
WebResponse wr = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe esta excepción?

Gracias.

Comment: Que versión de Woo y Visual Studio usas?

Comment: Cierto, se me olvidaba... es Visual Studio 2013 y WooCommerce 2.6.*

Answer (score 0):

Ese tipo de excepción se produce cuando no has inicializado un objeto el cual apunta a null. Verifica que hayas instanciado tu objeto httpWebRequest

```
HttpWebRequest httpwebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Saludos

Comment: Si lo tengo instanciado, lo tengo así:

httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(wc_url);

Lo que he podido ver es que cuando llega a ejecutar el método "GetResponseAsync()" es cuando me arroja la excepción...

Comment: Hola, se recomienda que en librerías se utilice [ConfigureAwait(false)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), en métodos en los que no se requiera del contexto de ejecución de sincronización como puede ser el thread UI. Un ejemplo en tu caso podrías ser `WebResponse wr = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: @RaúlBernalV, también te recomiendo revisar el StackTrace de la excepción pulsando en "Copiar detalles de la excepción al Portapapeles" como bien se muestra en la imagen que has puesto.